# How to format date with thymeleaf in a block

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

invoice.due value is
2025-03-25

That line

```
<p th:text="${invoice.due}"></p>
```

work great

My first attempt

```
<div class="date">Due Date: 
    <th:block th:text="${#temporals.format(invoice.due, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"></th:block>
</div>
```

In this case error is

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:
> Method call: Attempted to call method
> format(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) on null context object

My second attempt

```
<div class="date">Due Date: 
    <th:block th:text="${#temporals.format(|${invoice.due}|, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"></th:block>
</div>
```

In this case error return

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression
> [#temporals.format(|${report.invoice.date}|, 'yyyy-MM-dd')] @18:
> EL1069E: Missing expected character '|'

Answer (score 0):

The `temporals` thymeleaf object [isn't part of the Thymeleaf core](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time#status), which is probably why you are getting the first error. The `#temporals` object is null -- `Attempted to call method format(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) on null context object`. (Need to include it in your build.)

Also, the `format` method also expects a `Temporal` and a `String`. (And not a `String` and a `String` as you have provided.)

```
format(final Temporal target, final String pattern)
```

(Not sure why you are formatting the date in the same format as it starts in?)  Since you are just working with a String date, you'll have to convert it to a LocalDate (and use #temporals after including it in your pom) or Date (and use the `#dates` objects which is included in Thymeleaf core) in your controller first.